# How can I declare enums using java

Tags: java, enums

I want to convert this sample C# code into a java code:

```
public enum myEnum {
  ONE = "one",
  TWO = "two",
};
```

Because I want to change this constant class into enum

```
public final class TestConstants {
    public static String ONE = "one";
    public static String TWO= "two";
}
```

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: As for enums, there're many other correct answers below by now (and a must read link above) . Just wanted to add that if your class holds some constants like in your example (I am not talking about enums right now!!!) you can simply define interface this way: public interface TestConstants { String TEST = "test"; /*...*/ } Interface 'fields' are implicitly public static.

Comment: @Arturs Licis: Using an interface to hold constants is an anti-pattern. An interface is meant to define behavior. Use a regular class with a private constructor to hold constants. Static imports can be used to access the constants without putting the class name before.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Completely agree, that's why I said 'I am not talking about enums right now!!!' I just showed a more accurate way to declare 'constants holder' (interface versus class).

Comment: @Arturs Licis: My point is that you shouldn't use an interface to hold constants, but a class: public class TestConstants rather than public interface TestConstants. If you completely agree with me, why do you give this advice to the OP?

Comment: @JB Nizet My bad, I was into some other task at work, and scanned through your comment too hastily, so I thought you've mentioned that using enum as constant holders is a bad idea. Please excuse my inattention. However, I don't consider this to be a real anti-pattern. I understand the purpose of interface, but in this specific case I don't see anything bad (that could lead to mistakes) - you don't have to implement iface to use those constants. P.S. static imports can be applied to interface as well.

Comment: What If I want to do the quivalnet of setting a value of one of the enums to a combination of other enums? for instance in C# All = this| that| other

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
public enum MyEnum {
   ONE(1),
   TWO(2);
   private int value;
   private MyEnum(int value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }
}
```

In short - you can define any number of parameters for the enum as long as you provide constructor arguments (and set the values to the respective fields)

As Scott noted - the [official enum documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) gives you the answer. Always start from the official documentation of language features and constructs.

Update: For strings the only difference is that your constructor argument is `String`, and you declare enums with `TEST("test")`

Comment: What about a getter for `value`?

Comment: @Bohemian - I added it even before your comment :)

Answer (score 14):

[enums](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are [classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) in Java. They have an implicit ordinal value, starting at 0. If you want to store an additional field, then you do it like for any other class:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    ONE(1),
    TWO(2);

    private final int value;

    private MyEnum(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Quite simply as follows:

```
/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 *
 */
public enum MyEnum {
    ONE("one"), TWO("two")
    ;
    private final String value;

    private MyEnum(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getValue();
    }
}
```

For more info, visit [Enum Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) from Oracle Java Tutorials. Also, bear in mind that enums have **private** constructor.

---

**Update**, since you've updated your post, I've changed my value from an `int` to a `String`.

**Related:** [Java String enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978654/java-string-enum/3978690#3978690).

Comment: whats the advantange of declaring value as final?

Comment: `enum`'s are constants in Java so placing `value` as `final` just "reaffirms" the constant-ness of the `enum`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, in java, you can also create a parameterized enum. Say you want to create a className enum, in which you need to store classCode as well as className, you can do that like this:

```
public enum ClassEnum {

    ONE(1, "One"), 
    TWO(2, "Two"),
    THREE(3, "Three"),
    FOUR(4, "Four"),
    FIVE(5, "Five")
    ;

    private int code;
    private String name;

    private ClassEnum(int code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    ONE(1),
    TWO(2);

    private int value;

    private MyEnum(int val){
        value = val;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: why the underscore? And the typical convention is to have the field, then the constructor, then the getter.

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum NewEnum {
   ONE("test"),
   TWO("test");

   private String s;

   private NewEnum(String s) {
      this.s = s);
   }

    public String getS() {
        return this.s;
    }
}
```