# Constructor Enum error

Tags: java, constructor, enums

```
public enum ProductCategory {
  FOOD, BEVERAGE, DEFAULT;

private final String label;

private ProductCategory(String label){
this.label = label;
}

public String getLabel(){
        return label;
}
```

I want to implement method getLabel() in this enum class, but I am gettin error: "The constructor ProductCategory() is undefined".

I already have constructor that I need, what else I need to write? I tried to write default constructor but again I am getting error.

P.S. I am total beginner in java.

Comment: as a side note specifying an enum constructor as `private` is redundant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I declare enums using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007137/how-can-i-declare-enums-using-java)

Comment: One cannot write a default constructor. The default constructor is the one provided by the compiler for a class that has no constructor written.

Answer (score 3):

The error is coming from declaration of `enum` members: since the constructor takes `String label`, you need to supply the string to pass to that constructor:

```
FOOD("food"), BEVERAGE("bev"), DEFAULT("[default]");
```

Answer (score 1):

The *only* constructor you've currently got requires a string to be passed in - but all the enum values (`FOOD`, `BEVERAGE`, `DEFAULT`) *don't* specify strings, so they can't call the constructor.

Two options:

- Add a parameterless constructor:

  ```
  private ProductCategory() {}
  ```

  This wouldn't associate labels with your enum values though.
- Specify the label on each value:

  ```
  FOOD("Food"), BEVERAGE("Beverage"), DEFAULT("Default");
  ```

The latter is almost certainly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Enum constructor can be called while declaring the Enum members itself.

```
public enum ProductCategory
    {
        FOOD("label1"),
        BEVERAGE("label2"),
        DEFAULT("label3");

        private final String label;

        ProductCategory(String label)
        {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public String getLabel()
        {
            return label;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum ProductCategory {
    FOOD("FOOD"), BEVERAGE("BEVERAGE"), DEFAULT("DEFAULT");

    private final String label;

    private ProductCategory(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```