# Special characters in an enum

Tags: java, enums

I want to put the special characters, the parentheses ( '(' and ')' ) and the apostrophe ('), in an enum.

I had this:

```
private enum specialChars{
   "(", ")", "'"
}
```

but it doesn't work. Java says something about invalid tokens.
How can I solve this?

Grtz
me.eatCookie();

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978654/java-string-enum ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
private enum SpecialChars{
   COMMA(","),
   APOSTROPHE("'"),
   OPEN_PAREN("("),
   CLOSE_PAREN(")");

   private String value;
   private SpecialChars(String value)
   {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return this.value; //will return , or ' instead of COMMA or APOSTROPHE
   }
}
```

Example use:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   String line = //..read a line from STDIN

   //check for special characters 
   if(line.equals(SpecialChars.COMMA)      
      || line.equals(SpecialChars.APOSTROPHE)
      || line.equals(SpecialChars.OPEN_PAREN) 
      || line.equals(SpecialChars.CLOSE_PAREN)
   ) {
        //do something for the special chars
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me: my compiler complains: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from EnumTest.SpecialChars to String`

Comment: @Edward Did you override `toString()` as in the example above?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Yes, but using `if(line == SpecialChars.COMMA      || ...` did not work. Actually, when  calling the toString Method, it works (`if(line == SpecialChars.COMMA.toString()      || ...`) So, should this also work without calling `toString()`?

Comment: Sorry, looks like you found a 3-year old mistake :) In Java, you need to use `.equals()` to compare String objects. So the correct form would be `if ( line.equals(SpecialChars.COMMA) .... ) { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

Enum constants must be valid Java identifiers. You can override `toString` if you would like them *displayed* differently.

```
public enum SpecialChars {

    OPEN_PAREN {
        public String toString() {
            return "(";
        }
    },

    CLOSE_PAREN {
        public String toString() {
            return ")";
        }
    },

    QUOTE {
        public String toString() {
            return "'";
        }
    }

}
```

To check if another string is among the valid special characters, the enum constant must be surrounded with the `String.valueOf()` method and then compared with the `equals()` method.

```
String element = "(";
if (element.equals(String.valueOf(SpecialChars.OPEN_PAREN))) {}
```

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov You are _supposed_ to override toString() for every class you create.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov Oracle thinks otherwise: ["An enum type should override this method when a more "programmer-friendly" string form exists."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString%28%29)

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov What's actually not a good idea is downvoting competing answers :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with competition. There are bunch of specical characters that are just not printable (e.g. \n, \t, \r), so I stand my ground in this case. In this particular case, the parent toString() is actually more programmer-friendly.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov The OP did not mention non-printable characters anywhere in his post, so the assumption that he has any plans to use them is questionable, to say the least.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov the parent toString() for an enum will only print the name of the enum itself. With the parent toString() the OP would see `COMMA` instead of `,` which is not what they want.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen the OP didn't say what he want. Like I said, the "," won't really represent given enum and if you need an actual char, there should be a separate method for getting it. Oh, and don't even get me started on returning a String value for a single character...

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov When you print an enum its toString is called implicitly. I don't see any waste in returning my custom string when Java is returning its own string anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like this instead:

```
private enum SpecialChars {
   LEFT_BRACKET('('),
   RIGHT_BRACKET(')'),
   QUOTE('\'');

   char c;

   SpecialChars(char c) {
     this.c = c;
   }

   public char getChar() {
     return c;
   }
}
```