# How to compare string to enum in a switch statement in Java?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I guess I did not yet get the concept of `Enum`s in Java.

I try to compare Strings to my Enum-entries comparable to [Special characters in an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399207/special-characters-in-an-enum).

```
package com.stackoverflow.tests;

public class EnumTest {

  enum EnumTestOperator {
    EQUAL("=="),
    NOT_EQUAL("!=");

    private String value;

    private EnumTestOperator(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
      // will return == or != instead of EQUAL or NOT_EQUAL
      return this.value;
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line;
    line  = "<>";
    line  = ".ne.";
    line  = "!=";

    // Operator
    switch(line) {
//      case "!=":
      case EnumTestOperator.NOT_EQUAL:
        System.out.println("Not Equal");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Something else");
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

But in the Line:

```
case EnumTestOperator.NOT_EQUAL:
```

I get a compiler error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from EnumTest.EnumTestOperator to String
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're mixing up different types of objects; as Java is strongly typed this leads to errors

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing incompatible types. It's similar to the statement

```
"some string" == EnumTestOperator.NOT_EQUAL
```

where your compare a string value to an enum constant.

Just stop using enums and declare them as string constants:

```
private static final String EQUAL = "==";
private static final String NOT_EQUAL = "!=";
```

Then you can use them in the switch/case.

---

The other solution would be to find the enum constant based on your input. Add this to your enum:

```
public static EnumTestOperator byValue(String val){
  for(EnumTestOperator en:values()){
    if(en.value.equals(val)){
      return en;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

And then use the function like this:

```
EnumTestOperator en = EnumTestOperator.byValue(line);
switch(en) {
  case NOT_EQUAL:
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("Something else");
    break;
}
```

Unfortunately you will have to handle the `null` case differently since putting a `null` into a `switch` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I think you could also use the predefined method 'valueOf()'. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: @zypro no, you cannot. ``valueOf`` expects the constant's name (such as ``"NOT_EQUAL"``, which is not given here.

Answer (score 1):

`EnumTestOperator.NOT_EQUAL` is an instance of `EnumTestOperator`. You cannot compare it with a `String`.

You can evenutually compare `EnumTestOperator.NOT_EQUAL.toString()` with a `String` but not in a `case` statement (`case` statements require constant expressions in Java).

But you can instead iterate on `EnumTestOperator` constants :

```
public static EnumTestOperator find(String strValue) {
  for(EnumTestOperator operator : EnumTestOperator.values()) {
    if(operator.toString().equals(strValue)) {
      return operator;
    }
  }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("No matching value");
}
```