# Java if statement strings and more

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I have decided to try and learn a little in java tonight and i have just been trying some stuff with things i have learned.

My question is in an if statement how to i make two stings to be true.  Here is what i have so far.

```
if ("male".equals(gender)) && ("brendan".equals(name))
```

The problem i am pretty sure is the && but i am not sure.

EDIT EDIT EDIT.

This fixed part of the problem.
`if("male".equals(gender) && "Brendan".equals(name))`
and so did this

```
if (("male".equals(gender)) && ("brendan".equals(name)))
```

Now i will post the whole thing i am having another issue now and you would probably need to see the whole thing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class my_input_and_if_statements 
{
    public static void main (String args[])
{
    Scanner jonks = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name, gender, answer;
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    name = jonks.next();
    System.out.print("Hello ");
    System.out.print( name);
    System.out.println(" are you male or female?");
    gender = jonks.next();

        if (("male".equals(gender)) && ("brendan".equals(name)))            
            {
            System.out.println("blah blah");
            }

        else
            {
            System.out.println(" Welcome to one of my first java applications. I hope you like it");
            }

        if (("female".equals(gender)) && ("nicole".equals(name))) 
            {
            System.out.println("blah blah 2");
            }
        else
            {
            System.out.println(" Welcome to one of my first java applications. I hope you like it");
            }

            }
}
```

sorry if this seems kind of pointless just trying to tie some stuff in together before i start trying to learn some more.

now when i go through it gives me two lines when it finishes or it gives me both.

Comment: I don't really see the question here.

Comment: It works as expected. The way to find out is to *run* it.

Comment: Please post compilable code.

Comment: I think the 'error' has been edited out of the question.

Comment: Does [my amended answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13359591/68556) answer the second part of your question now?

Comment: Hey Edd.  That did it.  thank you.  I knew it would be an easy fix.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issues is your parentheses.

An if statement has the form `if(condition)`, where `condition` is some boolean expression. In this case you're wanting the condition to be `"male".equals(gender) && "Brendan".equals(name)`, so your complete statement should be something like the following:

```
if("male".equals(gender) && "Brendan".equals(name)) {
    //Foo Blah blah
}
else {
    //Barr fuzz fuzz
}
```

For the second part of your question, you have two `if` statements, both of which print on both the `if` and the `else` branches, so you're going to hit one or other of the `println` statements in the first `if` *and* one or other of the `println` statements of the second `if`. I think what you probably wanted to do was something like the following:

```
if(gender.equals("male") && name.equals("Brendan")) {
    println("Brendan's Message");
}
else if(gender.equals("female") && name.equals("Nicole")) {
    println("Nicole's Message");
}
else {
    println("Anybody's Message");
}
```

Comment: The two aren't exactly equivalent. One could throw an NPE, the other can't I think.

Comment: Good point. Let me edit it to focus on what I think is the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (("male".equals(gender)) && ("brendan".equals(name)))
   ^                                                   ^
```

`if(condition)` needs the enclosing brackets.

For your multiple comparisons, you could have a male or a female, not both, so you could use a nested `if..else` construct instead,

Otherwise, you will perform the male/female evaluation **for every name**, unnecessarily. The following seems **more natural** to me.

---

```
if ("male".equals(gender)){
    if("brendan".equals(name)){
        System.out.println("right");   
    }else{
        System.out.println("wrong wrong");  
    }
    //add more cases here
}else{
    //definitely female

}
```

Comment: Never thought about doing it this way but definatly makes sense when you think about it.  but it opens up another question.

Comment: like you have above.  how do you do the second else?

so it has 
<pre>
    if ("male".equals(gender)){
      if("brendan".equals(name))
         {
         System.out
         }
    else
         {
         System.out
         }

    //this part?
    else
<code>

Comment: it is not formating properly.  Give me a sec.

Comment: @user1820578 In that case, your `&&` based solution might be better. But if you want to add more conditions later, it will be harder. I'd implement it in the else like `System.out.println(" wrong wrong " + gender);` in order to differentiate between the 2 failed cases.

Comment: @user1820578 I have updated my answer. In your code, you are testing for female, even after ascertaining if male, in the above loop, which is IMO unnecessary.

Comment: I cant post this  to many characters.  Its a tomorrow job now any way.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One missing `(`, and superfluous parentheses.

```
if ("male".equals(gender) && "brendan".equals(name))
```

Comment: I don't think the braces are superfluous, although it's a bit of a contentious issue: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no

Comment: @Edd sorry, I meant parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to learn about enums. like

```
 public enum Gender
 {
      MALE = "Male";
      FEMALE = "Female";
 }
```

or this [Best way to create enum of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978654/java-string-enum)