# Efficiently converting java string to its equivalent enum

Tags: java, performance, enums, java-7

Given a string i want to get the enum equivalent of it in constant time.
I have a enum defined like the one shown in the question. [Best way to create enum of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978654/best-way-to-create-enum-of-strings)

```
public enum Strings {
STRING_ONE("ONE"),
STRING_TWO("TWO")
;

private final String text;

/**
 * @param text
 */
private Strings(final String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Enum#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return text;
}
}
```

If i now get a string (say "TWO"), is there a way to see if it exists and if it exists then is there a way i can define a method that will return the enum value (for example if i pass "TWO", i should be getting back "Strings.STRING_TWO"?

Comment: Is naming them `ONE`, `TWO` and using `Strings.valueOf(String)` an option? It seems repetitive to have `Strings.STRING_*`.

Answer (score 3):

Is [`Enum.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) not sufficient?  How would you imagine being more efficient than that?  There's (usually) no need to have an enum `STRING_ONE("ONE")` - just call enum value `ONE` and you get `.valueOf()` lookup for free.

Otherwise, just create a `private static Map<String, YourEnum>` and provide a similar `valueOf()` method that looks up against the `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Enum.valueOf` operates on the built-in name of the `enum` (i.e. `"STRING_ONE"` and `"STRING_TWO"`) you would need to roll your own "registry" of name-to-enum, like this:

```
public enum Strings {
    STRING_ONE("ONE"),
    STRING_TWO("TWO")
    ;
    private static final Map<String,Strings> byName = new HashMap<String,Strings>();
    private final String text;

    private Strings(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    static {
        for (Strings s : Strings.values()) {
            byName.put(s.toString(), s);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
    public static Strings forName(String name) {
        return byName.get(name);
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ZjFu6d)

Above, a map from string name to `enum Strings` is used to do the translation. If the name is not there, `null` would be returned from the `Strings.forName` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the code to be :

```
public enum Strings {
        STRING_ONE("ONE"), STRING_TWO("TWO");

        private String text;

        /**
         * @param text
         */
        private Strings(final String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return this.text;
        }

        public static Strings getByTextValue(String text) {
            for (Strings str : Strings.values()) {
                if (str.getText().equals(text)) {
                    return str;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see java.lang.Enum#toString()
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return text;
        }
    }
```

**Example :**

```
String test = "ONE";
Strings testEnum = Strings.getByTextValue(test);
```

now you have `testEnum` which is `enum` reference