# How to iterate through a Java enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum of string, as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978654/best-way-to-create-enum-of-strings).

When my current element would be STRING_ONE, how can switch to the next **Strings** item in the enum with for instance the ++ operator?

Something like:

```
 Strings myEnum = String.STRING_ONE;
    myEnum++ ; // to have STRING_TWO for instance
```

?

EDIT: I do not want to iterate through all of those enum elements. These STRING_ONE, STRING_TWO etc are some sort of states. I want to implement a `getNextState()` Method like

```
private void getNextstate(){
   myCurrentstate++;
}
```

Now, I have this, which does not seem efficient

```
private void getNextstate(){
   if(myCurrentstate == Strings.STRING_ONE) myCurrentstate == Strings.STRING_TWO;
   else if(myCurrentstate == Strings.STRING_TWO) myCurrentstate == Strings.STRING_THREE;
   //..
   else if(myCurrentstate == Strings.STRING_NINTYNINE) myCurrentstate == Strings.STRING_HUNDRET;
}
```

Comment: `x = Strings.values()[x.ordinal()+1]`

Answer (score 2):

In java, you can not overload the + operator, but you can for sure do:

```
   public enum Strings {
    STRING_ONE("ONE"),
    STRING_TWO("TWO")
    ;

    private final String text;

    /**
     * @param text
     */
    private Strings(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Enum#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

and then

```
for (Strings dir : Strings.values()) {
  // your code here
  System.out.println(dir.toString());
}
```

Comment: Your inclusion of a `text` property and toString override has nothing to do with the question, and only serves to make your answer much longer than it needs to be.

Comment: Read the question again, and go to the link, the CO is referring to please.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
for (Strings string : Strings.values()) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```