# Dynamic function calling in JDK8 with Predicate Object

Tags: java, java-8

I have a class which call country specific functions for different use cases. I want to generalise the logic in such a way that if I specify the country name & the method name, the same method for that country's class gets executed.

Predicate Class:- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html

```
private static void countrySpecificMethod(String countryName, Predicate predicate){
        if(countryName.equals("EGYPT")){
            // call the predicate function in EGYPT class
        } else if (countryName.equals("INDIA")) {
            // call the predicate function in INDIA class
        } else if (countryName.equals("HUNGARY")) {
            // call the predicate function in HUNGARY class
        } else if(countryName.equals("TURKEY")){
           // call the predicate function in TURKEY class
        } else if(countryName.equals("ITALY")){
            // call the predicate function in ITALY class
        } else if(countryName.equals("VIETNAM")){
            // call the predicate function in VIETNAM class
        } else{
           // call the predicate function in same class
        }
    }
```

Example:-

```
countrySpecificMethod("EGYPT", prepareAddress) 
 It should then call EGYPT.prepareAddress()

countrySpecificMethod("EGYPT", prepareUser)
 It should then call EGYPT.prepareUser()
```

Any help how this can be achieved?

Comment: What is a predicate function in this context?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html

Comment: That is not really useful. What are you trying to actually achieve?

Comment: Ohh got it, so I want to achieve a High order kind of Function here, where predicate for example can be `prepareAddress` & country be EGYPT. So the countrySpecificMethod should then call EGYPT.prepareAddress();

Comment: I just wanted to show what I need to do. It obviously will be a function name

Comment: But a `Predicate` is not a function name. It’s not clear why you think this interface is suitable to your task at all. Which is one of the reasons why no-one understood your actual task so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a lookup table to find the object from the appropiate class for the country, and lookup for the string identifier that matches the country.

For example a Map implementation, using a String as the key, and an interface or abstract class that defines the methods that can be called.
It would look something like this:

```java
Map<String, CountrySpecificInterface> countryLookup = new HashMap<tring, CountrySpecificInterface>();

countryLookup.put("EGYPT", new EgyptImplementation()); // EgyptImplementation implements CountrySpecificInterface including method prepareAddress()

countryLookup.get(countryName).prepareAddress()
```

You should put the string literals somewhere, to avoid repeating them all over the code. For example [use an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978654/best-way-to-create-enum-of-strings).

Comment: Since Java 7, you can write `new HashMap<>()` instead of repeating the type arguments.